# CSS can't be overwritten, no matter how ; Wordpress with responsive style_options.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So my problem is awkward, I have a Wordpress website on which I can't overwrite CSS. On which I've added a google font.

The problem is that sometimes when I want to overwrite a CSS using either a id and class selector, or embeding style into html, the font get's always overwritten.

How to overwrite css (font-face) which is coded in css in style_options.php which generates options.css.

Did anybody solve this problem already?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Is there a custom CSS option in your theme? You could try something using that option.

Comment: It is, and I'm using it, but still gets overwritten. That's why I've asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, if you want your attribute not to get overwritten, you need to use `!important` like so:

```
p {
    color: blue!important;
}
#myid {
    color: red;
}
<p id="myid">This text is blue.</p>
```

But i think you should check in your theme's option, there's gotta be some way to edit within wordpress such things as the font. (thanks  Vineet Kaushik for pointing that out)